# onBlur resets value in react-select

Tags: reactjs, redux, onblur, react-select

I have problem with react-select. When I type some text in searchable input and click outside, my text is disappear.
I tried `onBlur={() => input.onBlur({value: input.value})}` and it works fine but I have ugly errors in console. Something like `Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined`.

```
onChangeValue = (newValue) => {
  const inputValue = newValue.replace(/\W/g, '');
  this.setState({ inputValue });
  this.props.nameFilter(inputValue);
};

handleCloseMenu = () => {
  this.setState(({
    menuIsOpen: false,
  }))
  input.onBlur(input.value)
};

handleOpenMenu = () => {
  this.setState(({
    menuIsOpen: true,
  }))
  input.onBlur(input.value)
};

render() {
  return (
   <div className="container">
    <AsyncSelect 
      className="search-input"
      onFocus={this.handleOpenMenu}
      onBlur={this.handleCloseMenu}
      menuIsOpen={this.state.menuIsOpen}
      loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
      defaultOptions
      onInputChange={this.onChangeValue}
      placeholder="Search..."
    />
  </div>    
  )};
};
```

Is there any workaround without using redux-form?

The same problem like [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/805)  but I am not using redux-form and those solutions doesn't work.

Comment: Please, share more information.  This is not clear your question.

Comment: `onBlur` does not autoselect your option. you haven't 'selected' a value from the `options` array. Showing us your code may help.

Comment: Found a good solution here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-create-onblur-9hc4w?file=/src/App.js:1050-1092

Answer (score 0):

In the provided code, you are using 'input' but no where its been declared. You should pass it from props.

```
handleCloseMenu = (props) => {
  const { input, options } = props;
  this.setState(({
    menuIsOpen: false,
  }))
  input.onBlur(input.value)
};

handleOpenMenu = (props) => {
  const { input, options } = props;
  this.setState(({
    menuIsOpen: true,
  }))
  input.onBlur(input.value)
};
```

It worked for me.